# Django cannot connect to Postgresql on Opensuse

Tags: database, django, linux, postgresql, opensuse

I've configured everything as i would in another distro (i'm an arch user, and i installed opensuse on a desktop machine).

As :

- Django and all it requirements (psycopg)
- Postgresql
- Created a User for my django server
- Created a Database
- Granted all power for the database for my new user

Then, when starting syncdb to start working i get this message (I've changed users etc.. in this thread for user:question, password:password, database:question as it is in reality with other words):

```
FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "question"
```

After lurking i got the idea to change my pg_hba.conf file (located at : /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf)

This is what I have:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
```

My django conf file contains :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'question',
        'USER': 'question',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

I don't understand what i missed here, any ideas ?

Comment: Did you confirm that you connect with the same info via `psql`?

Comment: Sorry, i havn't but no i can't connect via the same infos via psql (with this command : su; su postgres; psql -U question; i get : psql: FATAL:  database "question" does not exist, this is returned after typing : create user question; as postgres and getting a successful message, however i can login if i create a database called question but i still won't be able to manage.py syncdb)

Comment: Can you try manually inserting something in the database when connected via `psql`? It sounds like a permissions problem.

Comment: question=> create table test(test VARCHAR(32));
CREATE TABLE
question=> INSERT INTO test(test) values ('test');
INSERT 0 1

Answer (score 1):

Edit the `/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf` file and change the method from `trust` to `md5`. This way Postgres will ask for a password.

Also remember to reload the configuration file.

Comment: Changed it to md5 and it still doesn't work. Trust should accept any input

Comment: Please also try to change from `ident` to `md5` in the `# IPv4 local connections` line.

Comment: I can connect via the command line and insert data into the database using psql -U question. I also tried to change from ident to md5 the IPV4 connections

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing:

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
```

to:

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

It appears that you are connecting via TCP (so the first line in pg_hba.confg with "trust" doesn't apply) and authenticate via [ident](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/auth-methods.html), which requires entries in pg_ident.conf. You probably want "md5" or one of the other password-based authentication options.

Comment: Changed it to md5, still the same error when trying to syncdb

Comment: Did you try any of the others (password, crypt)?

Comment: Ok, after changing IPV4 to trust it now sync. Anyidea how i could modify it to work with md5 ?

Comment: What's the error message when you change it to md5 and it doesn't work?

Comment: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "question"

Comment: That's the same ident error message as before. If it was set to md5, you'd see:

FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "someuser"